# Можно ли найти средний итератор между двумя итераторами по аналогии с индексами?

Tags: c++, итераторы

Можно ли найти средний итератор между двумя итераторами по аналогии с индексами? А так же проверить, первый итератор "больше или меньше" второго, так же по аналогии с индексами.

Comment: Почитайте что-нибудь про [категории итераторов](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator). Итераторы некоторых категорий можно вычитать друг из друга, прибавлять целые числа, т.е. работать «по аналогии с индексами», но есть и такие итераторы, с которыми так работать нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Ну... В **общем случае** что-то типа

```
...::iterator first, last;
...
advance(first,distance(first,last)/2);
```

Правда, надо гарантировать, что `first` находится до `last`, ибо

> The behavior is undefined if last is not reachable from first by (possibly repeatedly) incrementing first.